# Can I make the top panel blend with the launcher?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

When you open the dash, the top bar becomes transparent and the top panel, launcher and dash all seem to blend together, is it possible to make it look that way all the time, even when the dash is closed?

Comment: I really like how the panel looks with the launcher open, was going to ask this myself the other day.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the opacity of the panel by using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

To install CCSM, run

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

in a terminal.

Once installed, run it by searching for **ccsm** in Dash. Scrool down to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**, click it and choose **Experimental**. Here you can change panel and launcher opacity to make them look alike.

[image]

This is not perfect, but it gets you closer.